# An equality in normed space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space. Suppose that for some $x, y \in X$ we have $\lVert x+y \rVert = \lVert x \rVert + \lVert y \rVert$. Prove that $\lVert \alpha x + \beta y \rVert = \alpha \lVert x \rVert + \beta \lVert y \rVert$ for all $\alpha , \beta \geq 0 $.
I think it is sufficient to show that $\lVert \alpha x+y\rVert \geq \alpha \lVert x \rVert + \rVert y \rVert$ for all $\alpha \geq 0$. I'm wondering if the function $f(\alpha) = \lVert \alpha x+y\rVert - \alpha \lVert x \rVert - \rVert y \rVert$ is increasing.

Comment: The equality may not hold for $\alpha x$. I'm still in dark about that. Can you show it more clearly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $s\geq t\geq0$. Then
\begin{aligned}
s\|x\|+t\|y\|
&=s(\|x\|+\|y\|)-(s-t)\|y\|\\
&=s\|x+y\|-(s-t)\|y\|\\
&\leq\|sx+sy-(s-t)y\|\\
&=\|sx+ty\|\\
&\leq\|sx\|+\|ty\|\\
&=s\|x\|+t\|y\|.
\end{aligned}

Comment: @ MotylaNogaTomkaMazura: How did you see that

$$s||x+y|| -(s-t)||y|| \leq ||sx +sy -(s-t) y||$$

I know that

$$s||x+y|| -(s-t)||y|| = ||sx+sy|| -||(s-t)y||$$

why is it true that

$$||sx+sy|| -||(s-t)y|| \leq ||sx +sy -(s-t) y||$$

Comment: I think this is just the reverse triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Trivial if $\alpha=\beta =0$.Otherwise, let $ k=\alpha / (\alpha + \beta)$. The desired equation is equivalent to $||kx+(1-k)y||=k||x||+(1-k)||y||$ for $k \in [0,1]$. Let $u=kx+(1-k)y$ and $v=(1-k)x+ky$. We have  $$||x||+||y||=||x+y||=||u+v||\leq ||u||+||v||$$ $$\le (k||x||+(1-k)||y||)+((1-k)||x||+k||y||)=||x||+||y||.$$ The second inequality above is an equation,which requires $||u||=k||x||+(1-k)||y||.$ (And of course $||v||=(1-k)||x||+k||y||.$)