# $\|A+B\|=\|A\|+\|B\|$ implies $\|A+3B\|=\|A\|+\|3B\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Assume $V$ and $W$ are complex inner product spaces and $A,B:V \rightarrow W$ are linear maps. If
$\|A+B\|=\|A\|+\|B\|$ Then $\|A+3B\|=\|A\|+\|3B\|$.

This is from an old linear algebra exam and they did not mention about the norm. but it is probably the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm).

Comment: It is probably the norm induced by the inner product

Comment: Do you know when equality holds in the triangle inequality ?

Answer (score 3):

In any normed linear space $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$ implies that $\|sx+ty\|=s\|x\|+t\|y\|$ for all $s,t \geq 0$. See [An equality in normed space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435993/an-equality-in-normed-space/1436081#1436081)

This proof is independent of the norm that is given!

Comment: @Runway44 can we do that for matrices too?do we have to say m by n matrix is isomorphic to  vector with mn components?

Comment: Yes, you can apply this result to any vector space with a norm.

Comment: @user595419 I did not receive your comment in my inbox since it was not a reply to any of my comments and not posted under my answer. But yes, we can apply it for matrices, since $m\times n$ matrices are just "vectors" in a complex inner product space of dimension $mn$, as you say.

Comment: The norm unit ball $B=\{u:\|u\|\le 1\}$ is a convex set. If $x=\|x\|\hat x$ and $y=\|y\|\hat y$, then $\hat x, \hat y\in\partial B$. The given equality says that the  point at proportion $\|x\|:\|y\|$ in the segment $[\hat x,\hat y]$ is not only in the unit ball, but is actually on the surface of it as well. By convexity, this implies that the whole segment $[\hat x,\hat y]$ is on the surface of norm $1$, that is $\|\alpha\hat x+\beta \hat y\|=\alpha+\beta $ for all $\alpha,\beta\ge 0$. The claim in the answer, and also in the task, follows.

Answer (score 2):

It is true even if the norm is not induced from an inner product!

Just using the properties of the norm $\|\cdot\|$ and the fact that 
$\|A+B\|=\|A\|+\|B\|$, we obtain

$$
\|A\| +3\|B\| =3(\|A\| +\|B\|) -2\|A\| =3\|A+B\| -2\|A\|  \\
\le \|3A +3B -2A\|=\|A +3B \|\le \|A\|+\|3B\| =\|A\| +3\|B\|
$$
Hence
$$
\|A+3B\|=\|A\| +3\|B\|.
$$

Answer (score 0):

In a complex inner product space, $\|u\|^2=\langle u, u\rangle$ implies

$$ \|v+w\|^2=\|v\|^2+2\mathrm{Re}\langle v,w\rangle+\|w\|^2. $$

This is a so-called polarization identity. So if we assume

$$ \|v+w\|=\|v\|+\|w\|, $$

we get $\mathrm{Re}\langle v,w\rangle=\|v\|\|w\|$. Therefore

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \|v+3w\|^2 & =\|v\|^2+2\mathrm{Re}\langle v,3w\rangle+\|3w\|^2 \\ & = \|v\|^2+6\mathrm{Re}\langle v,w\rangle+\|3w\|^2 \\ & = \|v\|^2+6\|v\|\|w\|+\|3w\|^2 \\ & = \|v\|^2+2\|v\|\|3w\|+\|3w\|^2 \\ & = (\|v\|+\|3w\|)^2. \end{array} $$

The claim follows, since complex matrices form a complex inner product space (with the so-called Frobenius aka Hilbert-Schmidt norm deriving from the inner product $\langle A,B\rangle=\mathrm{tr}(A^{\dagger}B)$).

Moreover, since $|\langle v,w\rangle|\le \|v\|\|w\|$, the only way $\mathrm{Re}\langle v,w\rangle=\|v\|\|w\|$ is possible is if there is an actual equality $\langle v,w\rangle=\|v\|\|w\|$. This is only possible if the perpendicular component of $v$ with respect to $w$ (or vice-versa) is $0$ (exercise), so $v,w$ are parallel, so wlog $v=\lambda w$ for some scalar $\lambda$, but then $\langle v,w\rangle=\|v\|\|w\|$ implies $\lambda$ is a positive real.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for any norm induced by an inner product, equality holds in the triangle inequality $\|x+y\|\le\|x\|+\|y\|$ if and only if one of $x,y$ is a nonnegative multiple of the other. More specifically,
$$\|x+y\|^2=\|x\|^2+2\Re\langle x,y\rangle+\|y\|^2\le\|x\|^2+2\|x\|\|y\|+\|y\|^2=(\|x\|+\|y\|)^2.\tag{1}$$
If equality holds in $(1)$, then $\Re\langle x,y\rangle=\|x\|\|y\|$ and hence by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $x$ and $y$ must be parallel vectors. However, if $y=qx\ne0$ for some $q<0$ (the case $x=qy\ne0$ for some $q<0$ is similar), then $\|x+y\|=|1+q|\|x\|<(1-q)\|x\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$. Therefore, equality holds in $(1)$ only when one of $x$ and $y$ is a nonnegative multiple of the other, and obviously $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$ does hold in this case.

Now the statement in your question follows immediately, because one of $A,B$ is a nonnegative multiple of the other.